# Getting IE to stop treating ajax as cross-domain, inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I have the following setup:

`www.domain1.com/page1/` -- makes ajax POST request to `www.domain1.com/page2/`

`www.domain1.com/page2/` -- returns json response

---

`www.domain2.com/page1/` -- embeds `www.domain1.com/page1/` in iframe

---

When I load `www.domain1.com/page1/` the ajax request is made and everything works. When I load `www.domain2.com/page1/` in Chrome or Firefox, `www.domain1.com/page1/` is displayed in the iframe, and the ajax request is made fine.

When I try to load `www.domain2.com/page1/` in IE7 / IE8, the ajax request gives a FORBIDDEN error -- it seems to be treating the request as cross-domain and blocking it, even though the request is being made from `www.domain1.com/page1/` to `www.domain1.com/page2/`.

It works fine in IE when the request is GET, but not POST. How can I get IE to stop treating this as cross-domain, just because the entire flow is contained in an iframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably loosen a bit the security settings ( maybe enable "Launching programs and files in IFRAME" )

Answer (score 2):

jQuery v1.7.2 will fix CORS in IE, even if it isn't really CORS but IE thinks it is.
This simple boolean at the beginning of your JavaScript function should fix this behavior

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

This works for both GET and POST.

Comment: We had the same problem. Upgrading jQuery v1.7.1 to v1.11.0 (current version) did the trick. Thank you!