# Google Maps Embed not working on IE

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, iframe, cross-browser, google-maps-embed

I am embedding google map in my page. While it works fine on chrome and FF, it doesn't display in IE. I looked up extensively and tried changing the mode from embed to View. That didn't work either.

```
<iframe width="95%" height="460px" frameborder="0" style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MYAPIKEYHERE
&amp;q=120+S+Street+Name,+City,+CA+93117"> </iframe>
```

I looked on Google APi site to see if its not supported for IE. There was nothing mentioned about that there either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what version of IE are you using?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329201/getting-ie-to-stop-treating-ajax-as-cross-domain-inside-iframe

Comment: can you post a link to the page?

Comment: Its accessible only in internal network.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a known issue, caused when the page is running compatibility mode.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7675

According to Google, they are actively working on a fix.